$f\in C[0,1]\cap C^1(0,1)$ with $f'$ bounded, but $f$ not differentiable at endpoints
I'm looking for an elementary example of a function $f$ satisfying

$f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$,
The derivative $f'$ is bounded on $(0,1)$,
However, the function $f$ is not differentiable at endpoint $x=0$ and $x=1$.

I first tried something like $f'(x)=\sin\frac{1}{x}$, but to my surprise, it turned out that this cannot work since then $f$ becomes differentiable at $x=0$: See this MSE answer for more detail.
I vaguely remember finding a nice example here in MSE using logarithm, but I can't find it as of now. If such a function exists, it would make an interesting example for the second part of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2629767/42969

@MartinR This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!
